# Performant Async Request Caching

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have a storage/api feature which I want to incorporate the use of Promises in accessing the data. So far, this has been working quite well however there is a optimization point that I am trying to resolve.

Here is the example code:

```
class PromiseStorage {
    constructor(initData = {}) {
        this.internalData = Object.entries(initData).reduce((data, [key, value]) => {
            data[key] = Promise.resolve(value);
            return data;
        }, {});
    }
}

PromiseStorage.prototype.get = function(key) {
    // NOTE: this.internalData[key] is in most cases already a Promise
    // I am wrapping it in Promise.resolve to ensure that a Promise is returned
    // for example, in the case of "undefined"
    // another point to note is that this Promise always resolves,
    // even if the value is "undefined". The reason for this being that if you request
    // an undefined key on an object, this does not throw an error - just returns undefined
    return Promise.resolve(this.internalData[key]);
}

PromiseStorage.prototype.set = function(key, value) {
    // value could already be a Promise
    // the Promise.resolve is a fail-safe
    // to ensure it's a promise
    const promise = Promise.resolve(value);
    this.internalData[key] = promise;
    return promise;
}
```

This then works as follows:

```
const storage = new PromiseStorage();
const requestedData = new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => res(10), 5000));

storage.get('requestedData').then(console.log); // undefined
storage.set('requestedData', requestedData); // NOTE: this itself returns a promise with the value of requestedData
storage.get('requestedData').then(console.log); // after 5 seconds: 10
```

I then expanded the prototype:

```
PromiseStorage.prototype.exists = function(key) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        this.internalData[key] ? res(key) : rej(key);
    });
};
```

That way, you could use this as follows:

```
const externalStorage = new PromiseStorage();
const fnThatFetchesExternalData = storageInstance => file => {
    console.log(`fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for ${file}`);
    // obviously there would be proper error handling for failed/rejected fetch requests...
    const request = window.fetch(`/json/${file}.json`).then(res => new Promise((resolve, reject) => res.ok ? resolve(res.json()) : reject(res.json())))
    return storageInstance.set(file, request);
};
const requestOnlyIfNeeded = storageInstance => key => {
    storageInstance.exists(key)
    .then(key => {
        console.log(`${key} already exists in storage`);
        return externalStorage.get(key);
    })
    .catch(fnThatFetchesExternalData(externalStorage))
    .then(console.log, console.error);
}
// function is called here:
requestOnlyIfNeeded(externalStorage)('requested-data');
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for requested-data
```

This works great. However, there is a downside which I am trying to overcome. Take the following array:

```
const files = [
    'orders',
    'foo',
    'users',
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'bar',
]
const requests = files.map(requestOnlyIfNeeded(externalStorage));
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for orders
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for foo
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for users
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for foo <-- waste
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for bar
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for bar <-- waste
```

The waste here is that the second instances of `foo` and `bar` re-fetch the external data when the data was already being fetched in the first version. I have been working with various ways to overcome this. One idea is a function which filters the array first for unique keys, requests the data and then applies `storage.get`. However I feel that practically defeats the whole purpose:

```
const uniquePredicateFn = (n,i,a) => a.indexOf(n)===i);

// the Promise.all is there because a) then I can chain a then to the filtered list
// and b) because the filtered list is smaller than `files`, so I can't map it...
// (unless I did some interesting map/reduce function which might actually
// solve everything but be overly complex)
const hackyRequest = Promise.all(files.filter(uniquePredicateFn).map(requestOnlyIfNeeded(externalStorage)))
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for orders
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for foo
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for users
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for bar
.then(() => files.map(requestOnlyIfNeeded(externalStorage)));
// orders already exists in storage
// foo already exists in storage
// users already exists in storage
// foo already exists in storage
// bar already exists in storage
// bar already exists in storage
```

There's code smell all over that...

I could turn the array into a chain of requests (to execute one request after the previous one finishes), however, I feel that takes the asynchronicity out of this asynchronous function (and sequence of data returned does not matter here).

I am looking for a way for all requests to be asynchronous, but also not request the same data twice.

I would want it to go something like:

```
const requests = files.map(requestOnlyIfNeeded(externalStorage));
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for orders
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for foo
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for users
// foo already exists in storage <-- uses same promise as above foo
// fnThatFetchesExternalData was called for bar
// bar already exists in storage <-- uses same promise as above bar
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I've done something like this before.  If I understand your problem, one solution is to hold on to your promises and if any promise exists don't make a new one.

Comment: You would need to change how you structure your code so that you insert a promise into the cached storage (that will ultimately resolved to the value) BEFORE you do any asynchronous operation.  That way, you will never have two operations requesting the data.  The first one sets the promise in place.  The second operation, even if immediately afterward and before the first one has finished, will find the promise from the first one and simply return that same promise.  Then, you will never have two requests in flight for the same data as they will each just share the same promise.

Comment: And, you need to be able to synchronously check to see if the cache contains an item for a given key (not using promises).  If you can't do this synchronously, then you will need some sort of cache lock or some sort of semaphore to give you atomic access to checking the cache and acting on that result.  The idea is that you need an atomic operation for this sequence: check cache for a key, if nothing there, insert promise for that key, then fire off asynchronous operation to fetch that key.